# neo4j large scale data mmodelling

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j. I would need to build a money flow graph

My initial modelling is as follow but I am unsure if this would scale good.

```
(:Account)-[:TRANSFER]->(:Account)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Max DeMarzi blog post about scaling airports: https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/08/26/modeling-airline-flights-in-neo4j/

What you can do is to introduce month/day nodes between accounts and transactions:

```
(:Customer)-[:OWNS]->(:Account)-[:HAS_TRADING_DAY]->(:TradingDay)-[:TRANSFER]->(:TradingDay)<-[:HAS_TRADING_DAY]-(:Customer)
```

This way you could avoid supernodes. What you could also do is to encode the date into relationship

```
(:Account)-[:TRANSFER_2022_01_01]->(:Account)
```

This way you can avoid traversing all relationships between two nodes and filtering them by dates. This should optimize your queries as well, however the queries are a bit more complex.

Comment: Seems it would complicate the modelling and especially query a lot while I can do this with  breadth first search alone to traverse all path if there is a small amount of node and edges. While i initially `expecting is just turn it to acyclic path and using bfs/dfs only or neo4j` will auto cater necessary optimisation for me. Are there no simpler way then using all this "creative" thinking method?